# Print data via GET https://api.groovehq.com/v1/tickets

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I'm trying to get data trough a JSON API from Groove.

https://www.groovehq.com/docs/tickets#listing-tickets
and https://www.groovehq.com/docs

This is the code I made:

```
<?php 

    function timjson_front($atts, $content) {
        global $wpdb;

        $access_token = ""; //insert token
        $user_email = ""; // insert customers email


        $json = getJSON($access_token, $user_email);

        $html = "";

        foreach($json as $key => $waarde) {
            $html .= $key . ' = ' . $waarde; 
        }

        return html_entity_decode($html); 
    }

    function getJSON($access_token, $user_email) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.groovehq.com/v1/tickets?acces_token=' . $access_token . '&customer=' . $user_email);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $obj = json_decode($result);
        return $obj;
    }
 ?>
```

The code runs on a wordpress page and is part of a self made plugin. The idea is that the tickets from a customer gets printed on a page.

Wordpress gives a error at `foreach()`. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Or has some advice?

Answer (score 0):

**First**
You're iterating on `$obj` but `$obj = json_decode($result);` will [returns an object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). You need to iterate through an `array` so use `json_decode($result, true)`

**Second**
Based on the [API](https://www.groovehq.com/docs/tickets#listing-tickets), the first key is `tickets` and has multiple tickets
So you want to start with tickets in the foreach:

```
foreach($json['tickets'] as $ticket){
    foreach($ticket as $key => $waarde) {
        $html .= $key . ' = ' . $waarde; 
    }
}
```

**Third**
You're concatenating strings with `$html .= $key . ' = ' . $waarde;`
But based on the [API](https://www.groovehq.com/docs/tickets#listing-tickets), the values are not ALWAYS strings.

```
foreach($json['tickets'] as $ticket){
    foreach($ticket as $key => $waarde) {
        if(!in_array($key, ['tags','links'])){ // ignore the keys "tags" and "links" because they are array
            $html .= $key . ' = ' . $waarde; 
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: POC https://3v4l.org/dblmj